# What's the difference between "aspects of" and "aspects to"?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

I just wrote

> There are two strange aspects of this situation.

Then I decided that

> There are two strange aspects to this situation.

sounded better, but I don't know why. There are certainly many situations where "aspects of" sounds more natural than "aspects to". For example, it sounds more natural to me to say

> I haven't thought through all the subtle aspects of this question.

than

> I haven't thought through all the subtle aspects to this question.

But I can't quite put my finger on a precise rule for when to use which one. Is there one?

Comment: The preposition *to* works in the first instance, not the second. Cf. "There are two sides **to** the coin." HTH.

Comment: This question would have earned up votes if backed by research.

Comment: "Aspect of" is far more common than "aspects to", but neither one is technically incorrect in many contexts.

Comment: Consider, are there "sides of a coin" or "sides to a coin"?  Either one can be made to work.

Answer (score -1):

When using aspect in a sentence, you can't use 'to' for showing possession, instead use 'of'.

However, you can place preposition to when there's no talk of any possession, as in:

> - Moreover, the time horizon is another important aspect **to** take into consideration. [it doesn't show any possession here].

---

Your first example where you used 'aspects of' is absolutely grammatical other than your second example:

> - There are two strange
>     aspects **of** this situation. [correct]

And your second example might have been like this:

> - There are two strange
>     aspects **to** consider. [hence, using 'to' for showing possession is entirely ungrammatical]

Note that your 3rd and 4th examples are vice versa here. Same rules can be applied as I told about your 1st and 2nd example.

Also note that we use to in using other words, like belong and junior, etc. to show possession, property or relationship:

- ... belong **to** me.
- He is junior **to** me.
- What is he **to** you?

Answer (score -1):

The reason the first sentence sounds wrong is that it *is* wrong. Consider the following sentences:

> There are four sides of a square. [incorrect]
>
> A square has four sides.  [correct]

As this example shows, it is sometimes possible to reword a sentence that starts with "There is ..." or "There are ..." to make it clearer and stronger.  In your case,

> This situation has two strange aspects.  [correct]

is better stylistically than

> There are two strange aspects to this situation.  [correct]

Note also:

> There are two versions of the speech.  [correct]
>
> There are two copies of the photograph. [correct]
>
> A strange aspect of this situation is that we don't know who sent the letter.  [correct]
>
> One side of the building has been painted blue. [correct]

Comment: You seem to be saying that “of … ***a***” is incorrect, while “of … ***the***” and “of … ***this***” are correct.   Why?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that.  The problem is not with "of ... a" but with the construction "There are two x of y" when x belongs to or is contained in y.

Comment: You’re still making an unsubstantiated assertion.  ***Why*** is your answer correct?

Comment: Do you understand that "There are four sides of a square" is incorrect?

Comment: My gut tells me that it is, at best, awkward. But my gut isn’t always correct. And tparker (the OP) probably doesn’t care any more about your gut than I do. The question asks whether there is a precise rule for when to use which word, and you have not provided one. [Explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9414/26083)

Comment: I explained why "There are two strange aspects of this situation" is incorrect by simplifying it to "There are two X of Y" and providing an example in which this is obviously incorrect. If you disagree, please cite some texts that use a sentence like "There are four sides of a square." It is not possible to find a source for every single incorrect usage. That should not be a reason to discourage users from answering questions.